# Macbook trackpad freezes some applications

Tags: mac, freeze, touchpad

Lately I'm having some problems with the macbook trackpad. Some applications freeze when scrolling. I have noticed this problem with Chrome, Firefox and Evernote. Safari and Picasa still work well.

I've tried scrolling with a USB mouse and they all work ok, so this it seems indeed a trackpad issue.

I've been using applications to enhance trackpad and magic mouse usage, [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) and then [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) but since these problems arose I deleted them. It didn't solved the problem though.

I'm not sure, but maybe some system configurations were made by these tools and they remained even after the removal of these tools. So, my question is: how do I reset my configurations, specially those regarding trackpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two major possibilities in this situation :

1 - The trackpad configuration is crapped by the software you installed. That's what happened to me a couple of years ago, the only solution I found is to reinstall the OS and push out all configurations in the process but while keeping all the data it self (user files, etc.).

2 - The trackpad may be faulty, another situation that I got with my last generation macbook pro. For this situation I recommend you either bring the computer to the genius bar (the simplest way around the problem but also expensive). The other place where you can find new parts at a controlled price is [ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/Mac-Parts) then you can choose the model on the top right of the page... They have many parts and all the details needed to fix your MAC.

So I would definitely try a reinstall of the OS and do a full combo update of the OS. And then try to fix the component itself.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips. I was considering reinstalling the OS, since I found no other alternative. I'll backup my data and do it ASAP.